# What are some nice continuous mapping from the closed ball $\overline{B}^n$ to the $n$-sphere $S^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, parametrization

While proving that the quotient space $\overline{B}^n/S^{n-1}$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$, I needed to construct a continuous function $p:\overline{B}^n\to S^n$. I figured that by fixing two points $R = (0, 0,\dots, r)$ and $L = (0, 0,\dots, -r)$ in the closed $n$-ball $\overline{B}^n$ of radius $r$, I could then use the function $p(x) = \begin{cases}(x_1,\dots,x_n, \sqrt{r^2 - ||x||^2}):(x_n - r)^2 \leq (x_n + r)^2\\\ 
(x_1,\dots,x_n, -\sqrt{r^2 - ||x||^2}):(x_n + r)^2 < (x_n - r)^2\end{cases}$ (where $||x||$ is the standard norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$) to determine the sign of the $(n+1)$th component of the image of $x \in \overline{B}^n$. However, knowing that the closed unit interval can be mapped to the circle by the parametrization $x \mapsto (\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$, I can't help but to wonder whether some similar construction could be made from $\overline{B}^n$ to $S^n$?

That is, do you happen to know some nice/comfortable continuous mappings from a general closed $n$-ball to $n$-sphere, similar to the parametrization of a unit circle by a unit interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no map that "wraps" the Cartesian space around a sphere analogous to the covering of the unit circle by a line (because the sphere is simply-connected in dimension greater than $1$), but there is the map defined by
$$
x \mapsto \biggl(\sin(|x|)\frac{x}{|x|}, \cos(|x|)\biggr),
$$
which sends the open ball of radius $\pi$ about the origin diffeomorphically to the unit sphere with the "south pole" $(0, \dots, 0, -1)$ removed, and which collapses the boundary of the ball to the south pole. (This map is closely related to the Riemannian exponential map of a round sphere.)

Comment: Hats off to you sir! This is the single most eloquent mapping I've seen this whole year.

Comment: I have just one question, how do we deal with the division by $x$'s norm at the origin?

Comment: That does require care. The key point is $(\sin u)/u$ extends smoothly to $u = 0$.

Comment: Incidentally, if $n = 1$, this is the covering map of the line to the unit circle: The boundary of the unit ball, i.e., the $0$-sphere, does map to the antipode, but the map manages to be a covering because the $0$-sphere is a set of two points.